Use secret when defining task definition with AWS CDK
Is it possible to inject secrets into environment variables when building ECS containers using SecretString from SSM?
I would like to do something like:
taskDefinition.addContainer(`${id}-etcd`, {
  image: ContainerImage.fromRegistry(ecrRegistry),
  containerName: 'container-name',
  secrets: {
    ENV_VAR_NAME: new SecretStringFromSSM('param-name'),
  },
}


Tried with secrets manager:
When using the secrets property:
import { Secret } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-secretsmanager';

  secrets: {
    ENV_VAR_NAME: new Secret(this, `param-name`, {}),
  },

I get an error with:
Property 'arn' is missing in type 'import("/Users/<user>/<project>/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-secretsmanager/lib/secret").Secret' but required in type 'import("/Users/<user>/<project>/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs/lib/container-definition").Secret'.ts(2741)


Tried with different from... methods from the Secret:
import { Secret } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-secretsmanager';

  secrets: {
    ENV_VAR_NAME: Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn(
      this,
      `param-name`,
      'arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account>:secret:<secret-name>',
    ),
  },

But, as this class implements ISecret it is missing the arn property.
Property 'arn' is missing in type 'ISecret' but required in type 'Secret'.




Ideally you would add the text of the error to your post, not just an image. Text in images cannot typically be searched or copy/pasted.

Changed and added the message

Do the secrets already exist or is your CDK app both creating them and attempting to reference them? Presume you are familiar with the class Secret docs that show the required arn property.

They already exist

I'd investigate using the various fromSecret or fromSsm methods e.g. Get a value from AWS Secrets Manager or the earlier link I shared.

I guess I am struggling with Secret class. It is an abstract class and I don't know how to instantiate it

I also tryied as you suggested the fromSecretNameV2, fromSecretCompleteArn and fromSecretAttributes methods from the Secrets. And I get the same message: Property 'arn' is missing in type 'ISecret' but required in type 'Secret'

But you need to identify the secret by ARN, no? That's the interface being provided to you.

You're confusing the Secret construct from the aws-secretsmanager module and the Secret class from the aws-ecs module.
The secrets prop in a container definition expects the latter, while you're passing the former. You need to construct the latter yourself using its fromSecretsManager method:
import * as secretsmanager from '@aws-cdk-lib/aws-secrets-manager';
import * as ecs from '@aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs';

const mySecret = secretsmanager.Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn(
  this,
  `MySecret`,
  'arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account>:secret:<secret-name>',
);

...

 secrets: {
    ENV_VAR_NAME: ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(mySecret);
 },

...

